# Material-UI pickers - disable past but not show error

Tags: material-ui

We are using: https://material-ui-pickers.dev/

We want to disable past, but not show the error, if a date from the past is in there.  The reason is, that when you display the form, yesterday's date is not an error, as it was chosen yesterday.  If you select again, you should still not be able to select in the past.  Here is the code:

```
<DateTimePicker
        value={selectedDate}
        disablePast
        onChange={this.handleDateChange}
        label={this.props.label}
        showTodayButton
        helperText={"Required"}
      />
```

Answer (score 20):

You can disable all internal validation by passing

```
<DateTimePicker
  disablePast
  error={false}
  helperText={null}
/>
```

Comment: just setting
    error={false}
    helperText={null} will do

Answer (score 1):

```
<DateTimePicker
    value={selectedDate}
    disablePast
    onChange={this.handleDateChange}
    label={this.props.label}
    showTodayButton
    helperText={"Required"}
    minDateMessage=' '
  />
```

`minDateMessage` will render empty string. Besides, if border is still red, you can take the error's class and simple change its border color.